# Does Server.MapPath behaves differently in local machine and server machine?

Tags: asp.net, server.mappath

I have had a real nightmare with `Server.MapPath()`. When I call `Server.MapPath("~")` in my application that is running in ASP.NET Development Server it returns root directory that ends in a back slash like `f:\projects\app1\`, but I call it in published version, installed in IIS, it returns root directory without any back slash like `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\app1`. Why this happens? How could avoid?

I did 2 scenarios on a same machine: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, Visual Studio 2010 x64, IIS 7.

**UPDATE:**

Why I care about it? Ineed I have wrote a custom site map provider based on file/folder structure. It extracts list of file/folders of root directory `"~"`, replaces root directory section with `Server.MapPath("~")` in order to generate URL of `.aspx` files for use in ASP.NET `Menu` control. I think following code explains what I'm doing:

```
    string mainRoot = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(mainRoot); 

    //added to solve this problem with Server.MapPath
    if (!mainRoot.EndsWith(@"\"))
        mainRoot += @"\";


    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.aspx");
    foreach (FileInfo item in files)
    {
        string path = item.FullName.Replace(mainRoot, "~/").Replace(@"\", "/");

        //do more here
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be from when you set up the virtual directory inside of IIS, depending on whether you used a trailing slash when setting it up.

But does it really matter? Why would you even care what `Server.MapPath("~")` returns? I can't imagine you'd ever use it just like that. Much more likely is when you actually need a path to something *inside* your application:

```
Server.MapPath("~/Something/Foo.txt");
```

In addition, whenever you build up paths, you should try  to get into the habit of using [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx), because you don't need to worry about trailing slashes at all then:

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), @"Something\Foo.txt");
```

Comment: +1 about to make the exact some points. Probably from the configuration, shouldn't really matter.

Comment: +1 nice thought! I should keep this in mind myself, although I never had any problems with this.

Comment: see my UPDATE about why I care about it